# python formatter (autopep8, paste format) (VSCode)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, formatter, autopep8

I'd like to copy and paste some code but which code's format so dirty.

e.g.

```
n = input()

while True:
    try:
        if (int(n) < 10):
            pass
        else:
            pass
    except:
        break
```

after paste

```
n = input()

while True:
    try:
        if (int(n) < 10):
            output = str(n) * 2
        else:
            pass
        
        if (int(n) < 10):
    pass
else:
    pass

    except:
        break
```

I want

```
n = input()

while True:
    try:
        if (int(n) < 10):
            pass
        else:
            pass

        if (int(n) < 10):
            pass
        else:
            pass

    except:
        break
```

Also second one doesn't work formatter like autopep8.
I mean autopep8 can change second one to third one.

Is it normal?
Even option's are
**"editor.formatOnSave": true,
"editor.formatOnPaste": true**

Please help me. Thank you.
Have a nice day :)

Comment: What is the context? Are you working on VS Code?

Comment: I don't understand. Is the formatter changing your code to something you don't want or it's not changing it at all? If it's not changing it then you may just need to install it `pip install autopep8`

Comment: yes, I work in VS Code. I already installed it but doesn't work.

Comment: @Eugene -What are all the relevant formatting settings you use? Have you used the relevant formatted VSCode extension?

Comment: I dont know exact mean of relevant formatting. You mean extension? I tried "Preitter". But it didn't work, too. So I reinstalled VS Code and it worked. Now autopep8 or other kind of formatting program work well. Thanks. Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fell in love with https://pypi.org/project/black/, which is automatically formatting your code in your editor right before saving it. Simple to install, no maintenance. Just look up how to install it to your editor.

Comment: How can I use this as a formatter in vscode ?